# How to verify this recursion and how does the assertion follows immediately?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading Aigner's *Proofs from the book*, in the second proof on the infinitude of primes, it's said:

> [image]

He asks to *verify the recursion from which the assertion follows immediately*, It's not clear what's the meaning of verify the recursion nor how it follows immediately. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

The 'verify the recursion' means: prove that the Fermat numbers $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ satisfy the formula
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} F_k = F_n-2.
$$
The proof is per induction. The claim holds for $n=1$: $F_0= 3$, $F_1=5$. 
Now assume the factorization holds for some $n$. Then it follows:
$$
F_{n+1} -2= 2^{2^{n+1}} -1 = 2^{2^n \cdot 2} - 1 = (F_n-1)^2-1= F_n^2 - 2F_n 
= (F_n-2)F_n = \prod_{k=1}^n F_n,
$$
where in the last equality the induction hypothesis was used.